# Django 1.8 best place for custom validation of two fields on model level, where one of them is FK?

Tags: django, validation, django-models

I have model like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   number = models.CharField()
   menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = ('number', 'menu')
```

what I would like to validate is, that 'number' is unique within certain menu, but ignoring case. E.g if `('a1', 1)` then don't allow `('A1', 1)`.

1) **I want do this validation on model level**, not form.

2) **I want store in database values for number EXACTLY as given on input**

My first approach was to do it in model's `clean` method, but there always value of FK field `menu` is None, so I got `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`. Is it issue with Django 1.8 or it was never possible to handle fk fields in models clean?

I noticed that in `save` method I can acces FK but I can not raise `ValidationError` which will be handled nice for user.

What is the best strategy to validate it?

Answer (score 1):

See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14564).

In a nutshell, you can just `item.number = value.lower()` before saving.

Comment: If that's not too much overhead in your case, you could keep a column around just for validation purposes.